# Map.merge doesnt add value to ArrayList

Tags: java

i have a map and try to add value to an arraylist.

> Example: Key:1 Value:ArrayList(1), Key:2  Value:ArrayList(2), Key:3 
>   Value:ArrayList(3,3)

```
    String ss = "1233";
    char[] a = ss.toCharArray();
    Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>> mymap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (char c : a) {
        mymap.merge(c,new ArrayList<>(c), (o,n)->{
          o.addAll(n); return o;
        });
    }
```

but it doenst work, the value (ArrayList) is allways empty. What am I doing wrong? 
Debuger output:

```
mymap = {LinkedHashMap@418}  size = 3
        {Character@599} 1 -> {ArrayList@600}  size = 0
        key = {Character@599} 1
        value = {ArrayList@600}  size = 0
        {Character@604} 2 -> {ArrayList@605}  size = 0
        key = {Character@604} 2
        value = {ArrayList@605}  size = 0
        {Character@609} 3 -> {ArrayList@610}  size = 0
        key = {Character@609} 3
        value = {ArrayList@610}  size = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting empty `ArrayList`s in the `Map`, and then you merge empty `ArrayList`s, which results in empty `ArrayList`s.

Try:

```
mymap.merge(c,new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(c)), (o,n)->{
    o.addAll(n); return o;
});
```

or

```
mymap.merge(c,new ArrayList<>(List.of(c)), (o,n)->{
    o.addAll(n); return o;
});
```

Now the `Map` will contain:

```
{1=[1], 2=[2], 3=[3, 3]}
```

Comment: Thank you, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(c)) does the job. As Michael mentioned, new ArrayList<>(c) is creating an empty list

Answer (score 2):

```
new ArrayList<>(c)
```

is not doing what you think it is. It is creating an empty list, with an initial capacity related to the integer value of the character.

It is **not** creating a list with a single element.

Comment: "pre-allocated size" - that's typically known as the "capacity" of the list, to avoid confusion with `list.size()`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Right, badly phrased. Thanks

Comment: And, as shown in the other answer, `List.of` would probably be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I was creating an empty list

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Well, not `List.of(c)` on its own, since that list is immutable